# R bibliometrix package's thematicmap formatting

Tags: r, citations

I am trying to do bibliometrix analysis of articles using the bibliometrix package for R programming language. I have been able to extract the keywords from articles and everything works well using the code below. However, when I try to output the keyword cluster using the thematic map function, some of the keywords are overlayed on there. Is there a way to let each text display separately either from the network plot function or from the thematic map plots? See code and plots below

```
 NetMatrix <- biblioNetwork(M, analysis = "co-occurrences", network = "author_keywords", sep = ";")

S <- normalizeSimilarity(NetMatrix, type = "association")
net <- networkPlot(S, n = 200, Title = "co-occurrence network",type="fruchterman", labelsize = 0.7, halo = FALSE, cluster = "walktrap",remove.isolates=FALSE, remove.multiple=FALSE, noloops=TRUE, weighted=TRUE)

res <- thematicMap(net, NetMatrix, S)
plot(res$map)
```

The thematicmap plot is presented below[image]

As you can see, the texts to the bottom left side are not legible and overriding each other. Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
thematicMap(M, field = "ID", n = 250, minfreq = 5, stemming = FALSE, size = 0.5, n.labels = 1, repel = TRUE)
```

Change the **size** parameter